# How to sort words of different length in a row in excel in ascending order?

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel data as shown below (each cell has one word)

```
1.  AT  ART  TAR  RAT
2.  TO  OPT  TOP  POT
```

I sorted these words row wise using macros (as given below)>

After sorting I got the following result:

```
1.  ART  AT   RAT  TAR
2.  OPT  POT  TO   TOP
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Makro1A()
    Dim LastRow As Long      
    Dim FirstRow As Long     
    Dim iRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet    
        FirstRow = 2
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For iRow = FirstRow To LastRow
            With .Cells(iRow, "A").Resize(1, 10) 
                .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
                      OrderCustom:=5, MatchCase:=False, _
                      Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
            End With
        Next iRow
    End With
End Sub
```

But I am expecting the following result:

```
1.  AT  ART  RAT  TAR
2.  TO  OPT  POT  TOP
```

I want to sort words based on length in ascending order? What changes I need to do in the existing macro code to get this type of result?

Comment: I don't believe the [Range.Sort method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) does word length sorting...

Comment: This would be fairly easy if every other row consisted of the lengths of the words in the row above it (since you could first sort by length, then words). This gives you one strategy -- *insert* these rows (with the correct lengths), then sort, then delete the temporary rows. Alternatively -- write a custom VBA sort function for this particular case.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for your response. Could you please help me to write VBA sort function for that particular case?

Comment: @Kalyani Just take your favorite sort algorithm (e.g. quicksort). At some point in the algorithm there is something like `If A[i] < A[j] Then`. Replace that by `If Len(A[i]) < Len(A[j]) Or A[i] < A[j] Then` In other words, sorting ultimately boils down to pairwise comparisons. You just need to use the right comparison.